# Как правильно поставить запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно расставить знаки препинания: «на этом основании делается вывод: его значимость резко возрастает и значит следует ожидать ужесточения политического климата»?

Answer (score 1):

На этом основании делается вывод: его значимость резко возрастает и,значит, следует ожидать ужесточения политического климата. "Значит" - вводное слово. Запятая после союза ставится, если вводное слово можно опустить или переставить в другое место предложения без нарушения его структуры.